# VBA Excel Half of this loop works

Tags: vba, excel

So When i run this macro, the A column will be filled with `P`'s and the C column will be filled with `7`'s, just as I intended it to.

However I also needed the H and I columns to fill with `0`'s and `1`'s respectively.

However on the workbook, each worksheet will have the H and I columns unfilled. Only H2 and I2 will be filled. And in some worksheets the H2 and I2 will be the dates (1/0/1900),(1/1/1900) respectively. In other worksheets H2 and I2 will just have a 0 and 1, respectively.

Why is this happening? And why are some of the incorrect columns dates and others are numbers? How can this be fixed?

```
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

For i = 1 To Worksheets.count
    With Sheets(i)
      LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      .Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value2 = "P"
      LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
      .Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Value2 = "7"
      LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
      .Range("H2:H" & LastRow).Value2 = "0"
      LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
      .Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Value2 = "1"
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: In the ones that only fill H2 and I2 do you have any data in those columns beyond that to start?  Because you are finding and setting it to the last row in those specific columns that has data.  In the ones formatted as dates, just format them as general and you will get the 1 and 0 as desired.

Comment: You can also try to set the format using VBA `.Range("H2:H" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "General"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you have run the code twice and you do not see it changing any more. To see it adding more values every time you run it:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        With Sheets(i)
            .Columns("A:XFD").NumberFormat = "General"
            LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value2 = "P"
            LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Value2 = "7"
            LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range("H2:H" & LastRow).Value2 = "0"
            LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Value2 = "1"
        End With
    Next i    
End Sub
```

The problem with `(1/0/1900)` and `(1/1/1900)` is that these cells are formatted as date. And `0` is translated to `1/0/1900` and `1` is `1/1/1900`. To fix this, in code above the cells are formatted as `General` with this line:

`.Columns("A:XFD").NumberFormat = "General"`